# Hibernate throws QueryException when a querystring is executed

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, hql

This is the Hibernate HQL:

```
public Collection findByForeignKey(Long oidInfoComplementaria) throws DataAccessException {

        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from CadInfoComplementaria cadInfoCompl where cadInfoCompl.entidadInfoComplementaria.oid = ?" , new Object[]{oidInfoComplementaria});

    }
```

These are both entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRDTABCADINFOCOMPLEMENTARIA")
public class CadInfoComplementaria  implements BaseObject, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long oid;
    private EntidadInfoComplementaria entidadInfoComplementaria;
    private Date fechaCaducidad;

    public CadInfoComplementaria () {

    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="cadInfoComplementariaSequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="cadInfoComplementariaSequence",sequenceName="SEQ_CADINFOCOMPLEMENTARIA")
    @Column(name="OID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Long getOid() {
        return oid;
    }
    public void setOid(Long oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }
    public void setOid(String _tmp){
        oid = formatLong(_tmp);
    }    
    private Long formatLong(String _tmp){
        if(_tmp == null || _tmp.length() == 0) return null;
        return new Long(_tmp);
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OID_INFOCOMPLEMENTARIA")
    public EntidadInfoComplementaria getEntidadInfoComplementaria() {
        return this.entidadInfoComplementaria;
    }
    public void setEntidadInfoComplementaria(EntidadInfoComplementaria entidadInfoComplementaria) {
        this.entidadInfoComplementaria = entidadInfoComplementaria;
    }

    @Column(name="FECHA_CADUCIDAD", nullable=false)
    public Date getFechaCaducidad() {
        return fechaCaducidad;
    }
    public void setFechaCaducidad(Date fechaCaducidad) {
        this.fechaCaducidad = fechaCaducidad;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name="PRDTABENTIDAD_INFCOMPL")
public class EntidadInfoComplementaria implements  BaseObject, Serializable {

    private Long oid;
    private Long oidEntidad;
    private TxtInfoComplementaria txtInfoComplementaria;
    private String texto;
    private String flagEditado;
    private String codEstado;
    private String orden;
    private Set variables;
    private String codUsuarioAlta;
    private String codUsuarioModi;
    private String codOrigen;
    private String codFuente;
    private String codIdNFuente;
    private Date fecFuente;
    private Date fecAlta;
    private Date oca;
    private Long vsn;

    public EntidadInfoComplementaria() {

    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="entidadInfoComplementariaSequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="entidadInfoComplementariaSequence",sequenceName="SEQ_ENTINFOCOMPLEMENTARIA")
    @Column(name="OID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Long getOid() {
        return this.oid;
    }
    public void setOid(Long oid) {
        this.oid = oid;

...

}
```

And here is the exception throw by the program:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: in expected: cadInfoCompl [from CadInfoComplementaria cadInfoCompl where cadInfoCompl.entidadInfoComplementaria.oid = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: cadInfoCompl [from CadInfoComplementaria cadInfoCompl where cadInfoCompl.entidadInfoComplementaria.oid = ?]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:642)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:917)
    at informa.app.aig.produccion.dao.hibernate.CadInfoComplementariaDAOHibernate.findByForeignKey(CadInfoComplementariaDAOHibernate.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.findByForeignKey(Unknown Source)
    at informa.app.aig.produccion.service.CadInfoComplementariaSBeanImpl.obtenerCadInfoComplementariaClaveExtranjera(CadInfoComplementariaSBeanImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.obtenerCadInfoComplementariaClaveExtranjera(Unknown Source)
    at informa.app.aig.vista.acciones.InformaActionAIG.obtenerInfComplementaria(InformaActionAIG.java:393)
    at informa.app.aig.vista.acciones.InformaActionAIG.obtenerInfComplementaria(InformaActionAIG.java:346)
    at informa.app.aig.produccion.vista.acciones.SeleccionInformacionComplementariaEmpresaAction.mostrarDatos(SeleccionInformacionComplementariaEmpresaAction.java:323)
    at informa.app.aig.produccion.vista.acciones.SeleccionInformacionComplementariaEmpresaAction.realizarAccion(SeleccionInformacionComplementariaEmpresaAction.java:266)
    at informa.arq.core.web.struts.action.InformaAction.execute(InformaAction.java:116)
    at informa.app.produccion.core.web.InformaActionMigracion.execute(InformaActionMigracion.java:117)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1062)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1062)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: cadInfoCompl [from CadInfoComplementaria cadInfoCompl where cadInfoCompl.entidadInfoComplementaria.oid = ?]
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.FromParser.token(FromParser.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PreprocessingParser.token(PreprocessingParser.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:919)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    ... 96 more
```

I can't find where is the mistake. The HQL is written in a DAO class extended from an interface which is called by a Service class extenden from a interface too.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As I thought, the problem was that the Hibernate entity was not in the hibernate xml configuration file.